# What is the advantage that led C strings be implemented as zero-terminated character arrays?

Tags: c, string, null-terminated

What is the advantages that led to the implementation of C strings as zero-terminated character arrays instead of something where the length of the string is explicitly stored?

If I had to choose an implementation, I would have surely ended up with the second one.
In fact, the complexity for finding the length of a zero-terminated string is *linear*, while with the other possibility it would be O(1) (or slightly worse, but far, far better than O(n)).

To me, the choice which has been made seems very unnatural.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string#History This has some food for thought

Comment: Thank you, I found this interesting article cited by Wikipedia https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2010365